# Create a dynamic Tabbed View from Group By

Tags: views, routes

I created a View which show all the content tagged with user flagged terms and group the content by Term Name.

Right now I am trying to make each group appear in a tab, I don't know how to achieve it.

For example if the user "X" flagged terms "A", "B" & "C", Currently, The view come back with all content tagged with terms "A", "B" & "C" and group them by Term Name in this case "A", "B" & "C". I want these groups "A", "B" & "C" to be tabs. I need to auto generate them because I don't know either the number or which terms are flagged by the current user.

If I can't achieve it with views only, Is their anyway to achieve it with another modules e.g. Panels.

At the same time, I will try to trace the views template files to see If I can do it with jQuery Tabs and views template files. If you have any other suggestion please feel free.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Quicktabs](http://drupal.org/project/quicktabs) module is the answer.

Comment: Could you expand upon how you did this? I'm needing to do something similar.

Comment: Download and enable the Quicktabs module then in the view change the display from unformatted to quicktabs and select the group by field in the settings.